# Angular and Firebase data using iframes for youtube etc

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

i am building a app in angular and firebase as the backend, in the data section can i add iframe code and then link it to my view via ng-bind-html?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

for me a solution like this worked well:

html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="wrapper">
 <div ng-bind-html="fullVideo() | to_trusted"></div>
</div>
```

videoController.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

angular.module('myApp')
    .filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
        return function(text) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
        };
    }]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.videoid = 1;    
    $scope.fullVideo = function() {
        return '<video id="myVideo" width="100%" controls height="auto" preload="auto" poster="img/poster_nologo.jpg"><source id="mp4src" src="videos/video'+$scope.videoid+'.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>'
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi Danny, thanks for that, were you hosting the video locally?

Comment: yes, locally: 
src="videos/video'+$scope.videoid+'.mp4"

cross domain linkage should be no issue here.

Comment: Hello Sole, if you place the youtube iframe embed code in the return value, it should work as well.